# Populate textfield on page opening

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple form being opened clicking on tab

```
<form name="instructions" class="form form-horizontal" ng-controller="InstructionsPage">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="instruction">Instructions</label>
        <textarea id="instruction" rows="5" class="form-control" ng-model="instructions">
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="saveInstructions()">Save</button>
</form>
```

and related controller

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
       .controller('InstructionsPage', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
           use strict';               
           $scope.saveInstructions = function() {                   
               var data = $scope.instructions;
               // post request with data from textfield inside
           }
       }]);
```

How to receive data with GET-request to populate textfield with default/previously saved data? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update your `$scope.instructions` variable which is bound to the `<textarea>` `ng-model` from your controller like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.instructions = response;
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've catch an idea!

Comment: No problem. Good to know you can advance with your problem!